# A non well formed numeric value encountered on if condition

Tags: php, datetime, time

this if condition throw "A non well formed numeric value encountered" message.

```
if(strtotime($from) + $conHour*60*60 == strtotime($to)){

}
```

The error I see is:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

****var_dump**

```
$from = string(19) "2019-04-15 16:05:00"    
$to =string(19)"2019-04-15 17:05:00"    
$conhour = string(5) "01:00"
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($from);`,`var_dump($to);`, and `var_dump($conHour);` show? One of those obviously contains an invalid value.

Comment: see variable value first and brackets also `if(   ((strtotime($from)) + ($conHour*60*60) ) == strtotime($to) ){}`

Comment: $from - >  string(19) "2019-04-15 16:05:00"  $to - > string(19) "2019-04-15 17:05:00"  $conhour - > string(5) "01:00"

Comment: `$conHour` is clearly not a number so you can't do math with it. That is why you get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notice is thrown when you are trying to perform a math operation on a numeric value and a non-numeric type (string, bool, object etc.).

The reason that this may be happening in your code could be that either `$from` or `$to` are not valid date strings: see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php for correct formatting.

Another possible reason is that your `$conHour` does not have a valid numeric value.

EDIT: based on your update it is the latter: $conhour = string(5) "01:00"
you are trying to multiply a string. First (depending on how you get that variable) convert it in to a numeric value (`1`) and then you will be able to multiply it

Comment: see this $from = string(19) "2019-04-15 16:05:00"    
$to =string(19)"2019-04-15 17:05:00"    
$conhour = string(5) "01:00"